# How is "manifest.json" used in in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

The `manifest.json` file: a map between precompiled assets and the fingerprinted assets.

I understand what it is, but how it used?

In the Webpacker settings, a comment states
`# Cache manifest.json for performance`

Ok, but what job is the `manifest.json` performing where caching it makes it faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Webpacker::Manifest](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/lib/webpacker/manifest.rb) gives us that information.

```
# Singleton registry for accessing the packs path using a generated manifest.
# This allows javascript_pack_tag, stylesheet_pack_tag, asset_pack_path to take a reference to,
# say, "calendar.js" or "calendar.css" and turn it into "/packs/calendar-1016838bab065ae1e314.js" or
# "/packs/calendar-1016838bab065ae1e314.css".
#
# When the configuration is set to on-demand compilation, with the `compile: true` option in
# the webpacker.yml file, any lookups will be preceded by a compilation if one is needed.
```

When Rails wants `calendar.js` manifest.json says to find the packed version in `/packs/calendar-1016838bab065ae1e314.js`. There's an example a little later on in the code.

```
Webpacker.manifest.lookup('calendar.js') # => "/packs/calendar-1016838bab065ae1e122.js"
```